# How to delete a value

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to display the name of the value before deleting it.

Have no idea how to data bind in angular.

1.Angular html.

```
    <div *ngIf="pnlItemType" class="col-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th scope="col">Item Type Name</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-white">
            <tr *ngFor="let itemType of itemTypes">
                <td class="valign-middle">{{itemType.ItemTypeName}}</td>
                <td class="w-80 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
        title="Edit" (click)="editItemType(itemType)"><i class="fas fa- 
          pen"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td class="w-80 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline- 
           secondary" title="Delete" (click)="deleteItemType()"> <i 
          class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
               </tbody>
                 </table>
                    /div>
```

2.Modal view of delete box.

```
<ng-template #mdlDeleteItemType>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title"> Confirm to delete this item</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click) = 
 "hideModal();">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <span> Are you sure you want to delete this item? </span>
    <b>{{itemType?.ItemTypeName}}</b>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"> 
    Delete</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mg-rt-10" 
      (click)="hideModal()">Cancel</button>
 </div>
       </ng-template>
```

3.codebehind tsfile.

```
 deleteItemType(){

  this.hideModal();
  this.openLargeModal(this.mdlDeleteItemType);
}
```

4. I would like to show the name of the item to be deleted in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deleteItemType(itemType){
  this.mdlDeleteItemType = itemType;
  this.hideModal();
 //Just Open Modal after it
}
```

And your HTML

```
(click)="deleteItemType(itemType)"
```